# Racket macro with infinite number of arguments

Tags: macros, scheme, lisp, racket

I would like a macro that can take any number of arguments and return a list of each argument, like this:

```
(TEST first second third)
=> '(first second third)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like so?

```
(define-syntax-rule (TEST . lst)
  (quote lst))

(TEST first second third)
=> '(first second third)
```

or simply

```
(define-syntax-rule (TEST . lst)
  'lst)
```

Comment: Well that was easy. Thank you, kind sir. I'll accept your answer when I can (in 7 minutes atm).

Comment: Yes, as you see, no real need for a macro; `(quote (first second third))` is the same as `(TEST first second third)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way, using [`define-syntax`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html?q=define-syntax#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._define-syntax%29%29):

```
(define-syntax TEST
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ . lst) 'lst)))
```

Of course you can quote the expression directly, it really isn't necessary to use a macro here:

```
'(first second third)
```